# Кроссдоменный запрос для парсинга элемента

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. У меня есть страница на моем сайте http://www.mysite.com/, с которой должен идти запрос на сторонний ресурс http://www.othersite.com/ и возвращать содержимое, к примеру, элемента <div class="foo" />. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно организовать или хотя бы с чего начать?

Гугл читал, некоторые говорят смотреть в сторону айфрейма, некоторые говорят, что можно с помощью ajax, другие говорят, что это вообще невозможно.

upd: Второй сайт http://www.othersite.com/ - не мой, доступа к коду у меня нет.

Comment: В общем случае такое сделать нельзя. Нужны подробности про http://www.othersite.com/ .

Comment: Я в ручную могу открыть код страницы и посмотреть содержимое этого элемента. Грубо говоря, запрос не может сделать то же самое?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно что бы Ваш веб-сервер, который отдаёт http://www.mysite.com должен отдавать заголовок

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Это позволит получать данные с любых сайтов.

Comment: То есть сформировать обычный $.ajax запрос, только с параметром "headers: {Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *}" ?

Comment: @scarian т.е. сервер должен отправить такой заголовок. Автор ответа видимо не так понял задачу.

Comment: Когда загружается страница сайта, С КОТОРОЙ будет отправлен ajax запрос, вот тут браузер и должен получить заголовок.

Comment: не с которой будет отправлен запрос, а **на которую** в общем там где обработчик запроса надо header поставить, я бы `*` не рекомендовал, надо указывать mysite.com

Answer (score 0):

Можно:

Есть небольшой трюк с PHP. И этот трюк будет работать не только с Google, но и с любыми сайтами, к которым у вас нет доступа и вы не можете добавить Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Нам нужно создать PHP-файл (например. getContentFromUrl.php) на нашем сервере и сделать обращение к нему.

**PHP**

```
<?php

$ext_url = $_POST['ext_url'];

echo file_get_contents($ext_url);

?>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'getContentFromUrl.php', // link to your PHP file
    data: {
        // url куда наш сервер будет отправлять запрос, который мы не можем сделать через AJAX
        'ext_url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // теперь мы можем взять любые данные из внешнего url, потому что у нас есть вся страница
        var $h1 = $(data).find('h1').html();

        $('h1').text($h1);
    },
    error:function() {
        console.log('Error');
    }
});
```

**Как это работает:**

1. Ваш браузер с помощью JS отправит запрос на ваш сервер
2. Ваш сервер отправит запрос на любой другой сервер и получит ответ
3. Ваш сервер отправит этот ответ в ваг JS файл

И мы можем добавить event типа onClick на кнопку. Надеюсь, это поможет!